# Is MySQL event scheduler global?

Tags: mysql, database, events

Is MySQL event scheduler global or can it be set database specific so that in one database it would have status `ON` and in another database status `OFF`?

Answer (score 0):

> [23.4.2 Event Scheduler Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html)
>
> ...
>
> The global [event_scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) system variable determines whether the
>   Event Scheduler is enabled and running on the server.
>
> ...

There is no option to enable or disable by database, you can enable or disable events individually.